# I am unable to install wifi wireless driver bcm4311 on Hp Compaq nc8430 - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

```
tony@tony-lap:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4 
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5753M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:16fd] (rev 21) 
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

here is what I did to install bcm4311

//remove the old driver

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

//To Install b43 driver

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

add "b43" without quotes at the end of the textfile, note you can only use one module per line.

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add "blacklist wl" without quotes to keep the wrong module from being loaded on boot.

```
sudo reboot
```

click on system setting → click on “Additional Drivers” → select Broadcom std driver
–> click on Activate
I am getting an error after clicking activate on Additional Drivers,  Please help!!!!!!!!

---

here is the output.

```
tony@tony-lap:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

tony@tony-lap:~$ dmesg|grep b43
[   19.802871] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)
[   20.947260] Registered led device: b43-phy0::tx
[   20.947291] Registered led device: b43-phy0::rx
[   20.947320] Registered led device: b43-phy0::radio
[   21.124062] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 508.1084 (2009-01-14 01:32:01)
[   21.204649] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to DISABLED
[   21.212038] b43-phy0: Radio turned on by software
[   21.212042] b43-phy0: The hardware RF-kill button still turns the radio physically 
off. Press the button to turn it on.

tony@tony-lap:~$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off  
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: I ran the 2 commands below, reboot my labtop. sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree  I do not see my wireless light on when I unconnected network wired

Comment: after rebooting, I saw wireless in the network screen of "system settings". but I am unable to turn it on. please help!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The installation of the Broadcom STA driver by 'Additional Drivers' is incorrect for this device 14e4:4311. It adds a number of blacklists of needed drivers. It is not enough to remove the driver. In order to remove the blacklists, it must be purged:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and you wireless should be working correctly. Please stay away from 'Additional Drivers.'

Comment: I ran the 2 commands above, reboot my labtop. I do not see my wireless light on when I unconnected network wired.

Comment: What do these diagnostics tell us? rfkill list all; dmesg | grep b43; iwconfig

Comment: see the output above.

Comment: There is the answer: "The hardware RF-kill button still turns the radio physically off. Press the button to turn it on." Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your hardware is off. Try the physical switch on your laptop. Also try

`rfkill unblock all` command. The button may be "fn+f12" or some physical key on your laptop.